# What is the time complexity of this python code? Is it O(sqrt(n)) or O(n) because sum() has O(n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, analysis, space-complexity

Here is the code--
It returns the number of prime numbers less than n.

```
def countPrimes2(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 0
    primes = [True]*(n//2)
    for i in range(3, int((n**0.5))+1, 2):
        if primes[i//2]:
            primes[i*i//2::i] = [False]*((n - i*i - 1) // (2*i) + 1)

    return sum(primes)
```

Comment: You're not accounting for the time taken for the slice assignment.

Comment: The first line of actual code is `[True] * (n // 2)`.  That's already O(n).

Comment: @FrankYellin Shouldn't it be O(log n) because the sample space is halved?

Comment: @batman: If you double `n`, you still double `n//2`.

Comment: @batman.  Your question to me indicates you don't quite understand what O() notation means.  You really. need to understand what O(n) and O(sqrt(n)) means before asking what the O() of a particular algorithm is.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you! I got what you mean. I was not taking into account the time for slice assignment and even though for loop has O(sqrt(n)), slice assignment and sum() has O(n).